# Default radiobuttonlist in ASP.NET MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, webforms

How do I ensure that a radio button list has the first option selected?  If it is based on the model property, how is this set if this is the first page that is shown on application start-up?

This is easy peasy in webforms but I don't know how to do this in MVC and there doesn't seem to be anywhere on the NET which shows how this is done.

This doesn't seem to work:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SearchType, true) Location
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SearchType, false) Name
```

I Just get both radio buttons unselected??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Something, "radioValue", new { @checked = true })
```

Answer (score 6):

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Something, "radioValue", new { @checked = "checked"})
```

or if you are binding from model then

```
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Something, "radioValue", new { @checked = Model.checked})
```

if we try something like this where x.checked is binding from the database. irrespective of true or false. last radio-button in the list is checked, rest of them are unchecked.

how can we bind the Radio button list from Database and have it worked correctly?

Comment: You can not call `x` from outside the LINQ expression.

Comment: my apology it suppose to be Model

Comment: @Habo your problem will be solvedby using the syntax as in GeorgeMR answer below.

Answer (score 4):

This was my solution:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Coin , "Dollar", Model.Coin == "$" ? (new { @checked = "checked" }) : null)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Coin , "Euro", Model.Coin == "E" ? (new { @checked = "checked" }) : null)
```

Comment: Any reason or explanation will power your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting status, i agree both of above, for users who looking also checkbox can use below examples, and for radio button default i reversed the array, in my case below is right!

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                @for (int idx = 0; idx < Model.TldList.Count; idx++)
                {
                    <div>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.TldList[idx].Id)
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.TldList[idx].IsSelected)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.TldList[idx].Name)
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                @for (int idx = Model.Period.Count-1; idx >= 0; idx--)
                {
                    <div>
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => Model.Period, Model.Period[idx].Id, new { @checked = Model.Period[idx].IsSelected })
                        <span>@Model.Period[idx].Name</span>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
```